# htaccess で URL を書き換えてリダイレクトするには

Tags: .htaccess

企業さまのHPをリニューアルしているのですが、一部の記事でURLを変更することになりました。
単純なリダイレクトであれば私もやったことはあるのですが、今回は少し複雑なリダイレクトが必要となり、なかなか調べても出てこなかったので、書き込みさせていただきました。
ご存知の方いらっしゃれば、ご教授いただきたいです。

現）`https://www.example.com/news/20230531_48232.html`
変）`https://www.example.com/news/48232/`

現在のURL仕様は `ドメイン/news/8桁の日付_postID.html` です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/news/[0-9]{8}_([0-9]+).html /news/$1/ [R=301]
```

かなぁ？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます！
上記コード入れてみたんですが発動せず。。。

色々試してみて、下記コード入れてみたんですが、こちらもダメでした。
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news/[0-9]{8}_([0-9]+)\.html$ /news/$1/ [R=301]

Comment: .htaccess で RewriteRule を使用する場合、パスの先頭の「/」は省かれて渡ってきますので、『RewriteRule ^news/[0-9]{8}_([0-9]+)\.html /news/$1/ [R=301]』とするといいと思います。

Comment: みなさまご協力感謝いたします。
下記記述で成功しました。
RewriteRule ^news/[0-9]{8}\w([0-9]+)\.html$ https://www.example.com/news/$1/

アンダーバーを正規表現にしていなかったのも問題だったのかもしれません。